# NULL value when insering row with trigger SQL and CONCAT function

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, concatenation

I put 10,000 avatar photos on a server and I would like for each row inserted into the 'studenttable' table, the 'photo' column to be the concatenation of the url of the folder of my photos + the id of the inserted student.

However, the CONCAT function returns a NULL value with the basic trigger used.

First, here is the above mentioned table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `studenttable` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `gender` enum('Male','Female','Other') NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `birthDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `photo` varchar(535) DEFAULT NULL,
 `mark` double DEFAULT NULL,
 `comment` varchar(535) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and here is the basic trigger I created:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
create trigger IMAGE_LienApi
before insert on studenttable
for each row 
begin
  set NEW.photo = CONCAT('https://url-of-folder-with-my-images/',NEW.id,'.png');
end$$
DELIMITER ;
```

For information, the images are referenced in this way:
*number.png*

So when I insert a new student with this trigger, the photo column is always set to NULL.
The problem must come from *NEW.id*, because when I replace this value with a string, **it works**.

I also tried with

```sql
NEW.photo = 'https://url-of-folder-with-my-images/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),NEW.id),'.png';
```

but it did not work

Thank you in advance for your help and if someone could explain to me especially why the CONCAT does not work, that would be great !

Comment: new.id is not available in a before insert trigger

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT() returns NULL if any of its arguments are NULL.

In a BEFORE INSERT trigger, the `NEW.id` value is NULL. It hasn't been generated yet.

But in an AFTER INSERT trigger, it's too late to change the `NEW.photo` column of your row. You can't change columns in an AFTER trigger.

You cannot make a BEFORE INSERT trigger to concatenate an auto-increment value with other columns. The best you can do is let the INSERT complete, and then subsequently do an UPDATE to change your `photo` column.

The alternative is to forget about using the builtin AUTO_INCREMENT to generate id values, instead generate them some other way and specify the value in your INSERT statement.

Comment: Oh ok thanks i understood.... I'm going to try to do that directly in the code then by retrieving each time the last row entered and performing an update